# Swapping two rows or columns in Microsoft Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm using Excel 2010. Suppose you have this data in a spreadsheet:

```
line:   content:
1       data 1
2       data 2
3       data 3
4       data 4
5       data 5
```

You made a mistake and now need to switch the values in the `content` column (but **not** the `line` column) between rows 2 and 4. It should now look like:

```
line:   content:
1       data 1
2       data 4
3       data 3
4       data 2
5       data 5
```

How do I switch a column without changing the data in other columns?

To give another example, if I type

[image]

and then realize that I confused the small, sour citrus fruits, I want to select rows 2 and 4 (i.e., I want to select the *entire* rows),

[image]

and then automagically switch *some but not all* of the cells in those two rows.

[image]

Let’s assume that the column subset is constant; for example (as illustrated above),
I would always want to leave columns A and B in place, and swap columns C, D, and E.

No matter what table it is, no matter what data is there, no matter data correlation.
I need to select two rows (or columns), and swap them mutually.

- row1: abcdefg
- row2: hijklmn

Now after switching:

- row1: hijklmn
- row2: abcdefg

Comment: You don't seem to want to clarify the terms `row` and `column` with the term `cell`. Perhaps you should read a bit on excel terminology and some take another crack at a question that is a bit more clear, for us simpletons.

Comment: @Raystafarian The question is rather clear to me. The OP wants to swap two entire rows or columns, that's all. Rapier, if you would be so kind as to check our [formatting help](http://superuser.com/editing-help) which explains why the post doesn't look like you wanted it (but there's a preview window below for you to check).

Comment: @slhck that's what I thought, but OP seems to want to swap cells, not entire rows or columns. For instance in the first example `line` doesn't change at all, but `content` does; same for `lemon` going from `green` to `yellow`

Comment: Now I see what you mean, @Raystafarian. Yeah, they said "switch some but not all of the cells in those two rows" — the question is how to "automagically" know which cells are to be swapped when entire rows are selected.

Comment: Sounds like OP would need VBA that works with `selection` or asks for user input.

Comment: why complicate it ? pls tell me 1st how swap just whole lines, no matter is inside

Answer (score 2):

### Lazy way to swap cells

Use a VBA macro to swap single cells or congruent rectangle ranges

[image]

### How to use

1. Open Excel » Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> » Copy & paste the code to a new **module**
2. Go back to Excel and select your two ranges to swap.
   They have to match in size and cells count like shown in the example above
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and execute the `swap` macro.

---

```
Sub swap()

    If Selection.Areas.Count <> 2 Then Exit Sub

    Set range1 = Selection.Areas(1)
    Set range2 = Selection.Areas(2)

    If range1.Rows.Count <> range2.Rows.Count Or _
        range1.Columns.Count <> range2.Columns.Count Then Exit Sub

    range1Address = range1.Address
    range1.Cut
    range2.Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
    Range(range1Address).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    
    range2Address = range2.Address
    range2.Cut
    Range(range1Address).Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
    Range(range2Address).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    
End Sub
```

**Tip:** Assign a shortcut + Place the code in an Excel Add-In for even more comfort. Within an Add-In the new `swap` functionality is available in all your Excel sheets without the need to copy the code every time.

Comment: I'm tired and the code can't yet handle entire rows or columns. I'll update it tomorrow or someone else improve the small macro. I would appreciate it

Comment: nixda I have tried it, but I don't know how exactly. Never made it before. Pls can you describe step by step ? Thanks.

Comment: This code doesn't work. @JonMcClung's code works though.

Answer (score 2):

I found nixda's answer very helpful to use as a starting point, but for whatever reason it didn't work on my computer. With no VBA experience before today, I was able to come up with this, which definitely works, and also has the advantage of being a lot more comprehensible to someone without VBA experience:

```
Sub swap()

    If Selection.Areas.Count <> 2 Then Exit Sub

    Dim temp As Variant

    Set range1 = Selection.Areas(1)
    Set range2 = Selection.Areas(2)

        If range1.Rows.Count <> range2.Rows.Count Or _
        range1.Columns.Count <> range2.Columns.Count Then Exit Sub

    temp = range1.Value
    range1.Value = range2.Value
    range2.Value = temp

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the selected solution and it did some weird thing (i.e. didn't work at all) This one on the other had works like a charm. OP should select this as the answer.